# Which Ehcache imports to use?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am just starting out with Ehcache, and trying to cache the result of a method call in a JAX-RS framework. Can someone tell me what my class imports should be? For some reason I cant seem to find those lines in the (very confusing) examples I have read. I would also appreciate any links to Java method caching in Ehcache.... everything I've found seems to be trying to do very complicated things!

```
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.CacheManager;

/**
 *
 * @author king
 */
public class CacheTest {
CacheManager cacheMgr = CacheManager.newInstance();

//EJB?Stateless?
HelloService hello;


public Object getCache(){
    //Initialise a cache if it does not already exist
    if (cacheMgr.getCache("MyCache") == null) {
        cacheMgr.addCache("MyCache");
    }
    Cache cache = cacheMgr.getCache("MyCache");

    String s=hello.getUserInfo(103);
    //Store an element
    cache.put(new Element("103", s));

    //Retrieve an element
    Element el = cache.get("key");
    Serializable myObj = <Serializable>el.getObjectValue();
    return myObj;
}

}
```

ehcache.xml (in resources folder)

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <cache name="MyCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       eternal="false"
       timeToIdleSeconds="120"
       timeToLiveSeconds="120"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        >
       <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using an ehcache2 (net.sf.ehcache) configuration file while in your code you're using ehcache3 (org.ehcache)

Try again with a ehcache3 compatible xml file (you can find inspiration on the [ehcache3 official website](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/xml.html) or also [the peeper example](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/examples.html#xml-with-107-extension) or even [this little project I setup the other day](https://github.com/anthonydahanne/ehcache3-disk-persistence-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml))